# Asynchronous test code in Robolectric 3 with Play Services

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

I'm using **Robolectric 3 rc2** with OkHttp Mock WebServer and Google Play Services.

I need to **test the parsing** of a json and related processing associated to it using the mock server and the server client have already using. The whole server client call is running in **background** with **okhttp asynchronous** call. The whole project if a library project.

**Full code** [here](https://gist.github.com/HugoGresse/9b6fbc0ec8e677235a73)

**Gradle config :**

```
testCompile 'org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3'
testCompile ("org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2"){
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
testCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
testCompile ("org.robolectric:shadows-play-services:3.0-rc2"){
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0-rc2'
testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0'
testCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp:mockwebserver:1.2.1'
```

I'm running the test why command line :

> ./gradlew mymodule:clean mymodule:assembleDebug mymodule:testDebug --info

#### Error

I've got an **error** related to google play services `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock`

I'm surely doing something wrong when gettign AdvertisingId...

Complete stacktrace :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock
    at org.robolectric.util.SimpleFuture.run(SimpleFuture.java:57)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAsyncTask$2.run(ShadowAsyncTask.java:93)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.runOrQueueRunnable(Scheduler.java:218)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.postDelayed(Scheduler.java:73)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.post(Scheduler.java:60)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAsyncTask.execute(ShadowAsyncTask.java:90)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java)
    at com.example.sdk.adServer.ServerClient.<init>(ServerClient.java:101)
    at com.example.sdk.ServerClientTest.testLongTask(ServerClientTest.java:123)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:235)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:168)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:106)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx.zzbe(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx.zzbe(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.finish(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.finish(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.sdk.adServer.ServerClient$RetrieveAdvertisingId.doInBackground(ServerClient.java:459)
    at com.example.sdk.adServer.ServerClient$RetrieveAdvertisingId.doInBackground(ServerClient.java:452)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers$3.run(ReflectionHelpers.java:144)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.traverseClassHierarchy(ReflectionHelpers.java:241)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:138)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAsyncTaskBridge.doInBackground(ShadowAsyncTaskBridge.java:20)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAsyncTask$BackgroundWorker.call(ShadowAsyncTask.java:147)
    at org.robolectric.util.SimpleFuture.run(SimpleFuture.java:52)
```

Comment: I am seeing the same thing, I wrote a custom shadow for this class but it was not picked up by the executor.

Comment: It's not a solution but I've fall back to use Android Test which are working good... on a device.

Comment: @trev9065 See my answer below :)

Answer (score -1):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock
```

The message from the exception explicitly describes what you are doing wrong. Apparently you should not call AdvertisingIdClient on UI thread because the library doesn't allow it (the reason is stated above. It could lead to deadlock).

Therefore, you have to use **AsyncTask** or any other background task libraries in order to call this API.

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            AdvertisingIdClient.Info idInfo;
            String advertId = null;
            try {
                idInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context);
                advertId = idInfo.getId();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException|GooglePlayServicesRepairableException|IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return advertId;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String advertId) {
            KakaoTaskQueue.getInstance().addTask(new KakaoResultTask<EventsLogResponse>(callback) {
                @Override
                public EventsLogResponse call() throws Exception {
                    if (advertId == null)
                        throw new IllegalAccessException("Could not get adid from the device.");
                    rootEvent.setFrom(advertId);
                    return EventsApi.requestLoggingEvents(rootEvent, leafEvents);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    task.execute();
```

This is how you call **getAdvertisingIdInfo** method in **AdvertisingIdClient** class using **AsyncTask**. Comment if you have any other question :)